# read write permission in root of drive c: in windows XP

Tags: windows, security, windows-7, windows-xp, permissions

What is the best way to give all users of windows XP access to create/write to files in c: drive. I do not want those permissions to be inherited to all other folders on the same drive.
This access is a requirement to get a business critical app to function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cacls C:\ /G Everyone:(C)
```

That will grant everyone the Modify right to the top of C:\ and cause it to inherit. 
To enable inheritance, use this version:

```
cacls C:\ /G Everyone:(oi)(ci)(C)
```

The OI and CI rights are what govern inheritance.

---

If you're on Windows 7, it's similar. NOTE: the C - Change switch is now M - Modify in icacls.

```
icacls C:\ /Grant Everyone:(M)
```

icacls replaced cacls as of WinVista.

Comment: There is no modify switch on the cacls command ( in win 7 at least )

Comment: @Menuta Aaah! Win7! Even easier! Will update answer shortly.

Comment: I need it to work in both Win7 and XP, going to try it in a VM if I can.